# Can Game Boy games be played on the Game Boy Color?

Tags: game-boy

I tried putting a Game Boy Game in my Game Boy Color, and it fits, but I'm not sure whether my GBC is broken.

Will this work?

Comment: Well, you tell me. You tried it, right?

Comment: I wrote this and by the way I don't even know if the game boy color works

Comment: Most systems respect back compat, for at least one or similar systems, such as this. ie. if the cartridge fits, it'll likely work. Going the other way though (forward compat) will unlikely work

Comment: @Aequitas - Whilst true in many cases that games for newer consoles don't work on older ones, [this wasn't the case for the Gameboy & Gameboy Colour](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8P2i6JhyzyA)

Comment: @Robotnik yeh I didn't know, just stating what the usual case is.

Comment: There were two different types of GBC games - black cartridges (and some e.g. pokemon games in bright colors; there was also a difference in the shape of the cartridge case) which could be played on the original gameboy, and clear cartridges which could not.

Comment: Donkey Kong Country and it's subsequent sequels which for the original Gameboy worked well with GB Color.  I never put down my original Gameboy until I got my Atomic Purple GBC!  Those were the glory days of handheld gaming.  Good times.

Answer (score 56):

You totally can, and they should work fine. (I did this all the time.) If it is a dual mode cartridge (Typically dark grey or black plastic housing, in the same shape as the original Game Boy cartridge) it should have colour to it (a 56 colour palette), and if it is just the regular light gray plastic housing on the cart, it will have a 4-10 colour palette.

This [chart](http://www.nintendo.com/consumer/systems/gameboy/compatibilitychart.jsp) from Nintendo shows you what Game Boy era carts work with what systems, which should give you a good idea.

Comment: I believe it's worth mentioning in the answer how the color pallette can be changed: via a combination of the directional pad and the A or B buttons on the start up screen before the game loads.

Comment: Do you have any information on how well pre-GBC games that had enhanced color features from the Super Game Boy era were supported by the GBC?

Comment: @Random832 From the wiki for the GBC. "Titles that have color palettes on Super Game Boy will usually default to a similar pallette when played on a Game Boy Color." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_Boy_Color

Comment: The page does mention further down that a "small number" of older Game Boy games might not work on the Game Boy Color. If one game doesn't work, especially if it was made in 1991 or so or earlier (the GB was released in America and Japan in 1989), try another. You may not get to play the game you'd like, but this should at least work with a majority of games!

Comment: The GBC did not support SGB features, it did apply some default colorisations to known original game boy carts but unlike the SGB pallettes these did not change dynamically. Pokemon red/blue for example look very different on SGB and GBC.

Answer (score 30):

[image]
<sup>Source: http://www.nintendo.com/consumer/systems/gameboy/compatibilitychart.jsp</sup>

That should tell you all you need to know about the compatibility. Short answer: Yes, you can.

Update to point out main points:

- Firstly, inserting an original GameBoy game will display up to 4-10 colours. The colour scheme can be changed using special palettes.
- A small number is said to possibly not function properly as sometimes there may be scrambled images, sound problems or missing graphics.

To add to this, to change colour palettes, here a few key presses you can perform (you have to do this at the startup screen:

- Brown: Up directional key
- Blue: Left directional key
- Pastel mix: Down directional key
- Green: Right directional key
- Red: Up + A
- Dark Blue: Left + A
- Orange: Down + A
- Dark Green: Right + A
- Dark Brown: Up + B
- Gray: Left + B
- Yellow: Down + B
- Reverse: Right + B

Hope this was a bit more informative than my short answer :).

Answer (score 6):

So far, every handheld system Nintendo has made has been designed with a [Poka-yoke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poka-yoke) such that it is impossible to insert any cartridge into a system with which it is not compatible. If you get a GB classic cartridge, a GB color cartridge, a GB advance one, and so on, and carefully examine and compare their shapes, you'll notice the differences and how/why older cartridges can go into newer systems, but the newer cartridges won't fit into the older systems.

Comment: Never heard that term, but this is what I immediately thought of.

Comment: The name Baka-Yoke is more realistic.

Comment: @ardaozkal "Realistic"? I don't see how those two terms can be evaluated on a realism scale. In any event, I chose to use the term Poka-yoke because that is the title of the Wikipedia article I linked to. Also, that article explains the reason that the wiki editors elected to use the one term over the other.

Comment: @DanHenderson Baka-yoke roughly means "stupid proof" :P

Comment: Or, more conceptually, "foolproof". Whereas Poka-yoke means "mistake-proof" or "error-proof". Regardless, "realism" isn't a valid comparison - that would imply that one term or the other is _imaginary_ or _fantasy,_ neither of which are sensible assessments.

Comment: Pretty sure this is wrong, specifically i'm pretty sure you can put a GBC only cartridge into the game boy poket, turn it on and get an error message. IIRC with the original gameboy you can insert a gamboy color only cartridge but you can't turn the gameboy on.

Comment: The GameBoy Pocket is sort of a mid-term variant of a console, and is an exception - but yeah, in general, if you inserted a cartridge into a console that can't read it, i Not all "Mistake-proof" systems work 100$ of the time, but they generally make it harder (i.e. The reason the GameBoy original won't boot is because of that switch-lock - you *could* remove the part that jams, but it's more work than realizing it won't work as intended.).

Answer (score 1):

All Game Boy Game Paks except maybe a half dozen will work on Game Boy Color.

- *Road Rash* and *Xerd no Densetsu* do not run on Game Boy Color because they inadvertently rely on the effect of a bug in STAT IRQ, a feature to synchronize the CPU to video display. This bug affects only Game Boy, Super Game Boy, Game Boy pocket, and Game Boy Light. No bug, no game.
- The Game Link connector on the Game Boy pocket and later is smaller than on the original Game Boy. Any accessory with a captive cable, such as player 1 on the 4-player adapter for *F-1 Race* or the keyboard for the unreleased *Workboy* organizer software, will not connect.
- Depending on the SoC revision, some games may have audio changes. The [wave (bass) channel in *R-Type*](http://gbdev.gg8.se/wiki/articles/Gameboy_sound_hardware#Power_Control), the score counting after a level in *Panel Action Bingo*, and everything in *Prehistorik Man* are examples.
- Game Boy Advance Game Paks neither fit nor run.

Answer (score 0):

Does the -Nintendo- logo show up when you turn it on?  If I remember correct, it should show up regardless of whether there is a game inserted, and indicates the GBC is operational.

If it isn't working, then it does sound like either the GBC is broken, or the games are broken.

The GBC was designed to be completely backwards compatible with GB games, and it enhanced them with color.  Which added replay value to old GB games.

One thing I like about playing GB games in the GBC is that you can infer that Nintendo provided a well thought out game engine to GB developers, from the very beginning.  In my experience, for all pre-GBC games I played (Mario, Zelda, Star Trek), the player was one color (blue?), the enemy sprites were another (red?), and the background was another color (green?).  This made the action games somewhat easier, as red moving objects are easier to see than merely moving objects.

Another thing I liked was the battery life, which was even better than the GB Pocket.  If the battery leads are corroded, I find that vinegar on a q-tip is a good way of clearing away the corrosion and/or dead battery acids.

Comment: I have a GBC, and the Nintendo logo only shows up if a game is inserted.  Otherwise, there's a solid black rectangle in it's place.  (The "GAME BOY" logo and animation shows up regardless of whether a game is inserted though.)